# How to determine which version of a yum library is compatible with a specific version of a dependency that is already installed?

Tags: redhat, yum

I am attempting to install the libcap-devel library via yum, and it looks like my company's yum repo only has `libcap-devel-2.22-8.el7.x86_64`, which requires `glibc-common-2.17-105.el7`.

Unfortunately, the glibc-common installed on my VM is `glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64`, and the installation fails.

I want to figure out how to determine which version of `libcap-devel` is compatible with `glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64`, and then ask the sysadmins to add this verion of `libcap-devel` to the yum repo (which I am not authorized to do) so that I can install it successfully. How do I do this?

Here is the output of `yum install libcap-devel`

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libcap-devel.x86_64 0:2.22-8.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcap = 2.22-8.el7 for package: libcap-devel-2.22-8.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libcap.i686 0:2.22-8.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libattr.so.1 for package: libcap-2.22-8.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libattr.so.1(ATTR_1.0) for package: libcap-2.22-8.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8) for package: libcap-2.22-8.el7.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.17-105.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.17-105.el7 for package: glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686
---> Package libattr.i686 0:2.4.46-12.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.17-105.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.17-105.el7 for package: glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.16.2.3-13.el7_1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
Error: Package: glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686 (redhat_base)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-105.el7
           Installed: glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.5)
               glibc-common = 2.17-222.el7
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64 (redhat_base)
               glibc-common = 2.17-105.el7
```

Here is the output of `yum --showduplicates list libcap-devel`, which shows that the yum repo only has one version available:

```
========================== N/S matched: libcap-devel ===========================
libcap-devel-2.22-8.el7.i686 : Development files for libcap
libcap-devel-2.22-8.el7.x86_64 : Development files for libcap
```

---

The output of `yum --showduplicates list libcap` shows:

```
Installed Packages
libcap.x86_64                      2.22-9.el7                      @anaconda/7.5
Available Packages
libcap.i686                        2.22-8.el7                      redhat_base  
libcap.x86_64                      2.22-8.el7                      redhat_base
```

The output of `yum install -y libcap-2.22-8.el7.x86_64` shows:

Package matching libcap-2.22-8.el7.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do

After this, running `yum install -y libcap-devel-2.22-8.el7.x86_64` still attempts to download the 32 bit version:

```
...
--> Processing Dependency: libcap = 2.22-8.el7 for package: libcap-devel-2.22-8.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libcap.i686 0:2.22-8.el7 will be installed
...
```

---

The output of `yum --showduplicates list glibc` shows glibc.i686 0:2.17-222.el7 is not available, only 2.17-105.e17 is.

```
Installed Packages
glibc.x86_64                     2.17-222.el7                      @anaconda/7.5
Available Packages
glibc.i686                       2.17-105.el7                      redhat_base  
glibc.x86_64                     2.17-105.el7                      redhat_base
```

---

Any variation of this fails:

```
yum downgrade -y glibc-2.17-105.el7
yum downgrade -y glibc-2.17-105.el7 glibc-common-2.17-105.el7
yum downgrade -y glibc-2.17-105.el7 glibc-common-2.17-105.el7 glibc-devel-2.17-105.el7
yum downgrade -y glibc-headers-2.17-105.el7 glibc-2.17-105.el7 glibc-common-2.17-105.el7 glibc-devel-2.17-105.el7
```

For example the first command complains about glibc-common and glibc-devel, adding these in results in a complaint about glibc-headers, and the fourth line actually segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the jungle of library/rpm dependencies :)

It takes some time and patience to read, and then some skill to read the `yum` output. Sometimes you'll even have to run some intermediate commands to get the exact answer, but let's see what we can already see here:

> Processing Dependency: libcap = 2.22-8.el7 for package: libcap-devel-2.22-8.el7.x86_64

You try to install `libcap-devel`. `yum` says he will also need to install `libcap` with the exact same version number. No surprises so far.

> Package libcap.i686 0:2.22-8.el7 will be installed

This is probably already something you do not want. You seem to be on a 64 bit system; do you really want the i686 version of this library installed? The fact is `libcap-devel` does not say it requires the x86_64 version; it requires any of the two. Preferably `yum` will install the x86_64 version, but if that is impossible the i686 version will do.

In this case I would suggest you to first try installing `libcap-2.22-8.el7.x86_64` and see why `yum` won't install that one.

But in any case let's just read on, this will give you also information on how to solve this problem for the x86_64 package.

> --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8) for package: libcap-2.22-8.el7.i686
>
> --> Running transaction check
>
> ---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.17-105.el7 will be installed

so here `yum` chose to install `glibc.i686 0:2.17-105.el7` , probably to satisfy the `libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8)`

now this is where the conflict occurs: `glibc.i686 0:2.17-105.el7` requires `glibc-common` with the exact same version number, but you already have a more recent version of `glibc-common` on your machine.

## Possible solutions

There are multiple solutions here, a non-exhaustive list in order of my preference:

1. investigate why `libcap-2.22-8.el7.x86_64` can't be installed.
2. make sure `glibc.i686 0:2.17-222.el7` is available in your `yum` repositories (or installed on your system)
3. downgrade you `glibc-common` (and probably also `glibc` x86_64 version) to version 0:2.17-105.el7

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'v edited my post - it turns out `libcap-2.22-8.el7.x86_64` is already installed; `glibc.i686 0:2.17-222.el7` is available and the X86_64 version is already installed, and any attempt to downlown glibc-common failed :/.

Comment: It seems like `glibc.i686 0:2.17-222.el7` is not available according to your edit. You can search this package online and install it. I think this should unblock you.